# Why is the State of the Union Address Called 一般教書演説?

Tags: etymology, compounds

The President of the United States gives a speech referred to in English as the "State of the Union". Why is this speech called 一般教書演説{いっぱんきょうしょえんぜつ} in Japanese?

Comment: It has only relatively recently been referred to as the 'State of the Union Address'. Checking the English etymology might yield answers for you.

Comment: Have you tried to break it down: [一般](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%80%E8%88%AC) + [教書](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%95%99%E6%9B%B8) + [演説](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%BC%94%E8%AA%AC)?

Comment: "General (Official)Message Speech" makes some sense, but why isn't this term in Japanese a translation of "State of the Union" like, 国家連合現状報告演説 -> 国連現報演説 -> 国連現報 or something like that instead? Even 国家教書演説 would make more sense to me personally. But maybe I just need to look up what @user27280 is talking about...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user27280 mentions, in English it [used to be known by a different name](https://www.senate.gov/artandhistory/history/resources/pdf/stateoftheunion.pdf):

> **Has the Message Always Been Known by this Name?**
>
> The message was generally known as “the President’s Annual Message to
> Congress” until well into the 20th century. Although some historians
> suggest that the phrase “State of the Union” emerged only after World
> War II, President Franklin Roosevelt’s 1934 message is identified in
> his papers as his “Annual Message to Congress on the State of the
> Union.” According to the Office of the Clerk of the House of
> Representatives, it was known informally as the State of the Union
> Address from 1942 to 1946, and has been known “generally” by the same
> name since 1947.

I found [a Japanese document from 1941](https://www.jacar.go.jp/nichibei/popup/19410106a.html), which calls it

> 「（２５）昭和十六年一月六日「ルーズヴェルト」ノ**一般議会教書**」

[image: President Roosevelt's message to the Seventy-seventh Congress]

So the 一般教書 part of the term predates it being widespread to call it the ***State of the Union*** in English. I think the 一般 is to distinguish it from other messages of the President to Congress such as The Budget Message (予算教書),  Annual Economic Report (経済報告–this one isn't a 教書), and whatever other special messages the President might want to give (for example [Kennedy's 1963 speech on mental health](https://www.jfklibrary.org/asset-viewer/archives/JFKPOF/052/JFKPOF-052-012) is translated as [精神病及び精神薄弱に関する大統領教書](http://www.ritsumei.ac.jp/acd/gr/gsce/ce/2010/mk01.pdf)). Even though the name of the speech changed in English, it's not surprising that it might not have changed so drastically in Japanese.

EDIT:  The earliest source of 一般教書 directly I can find is in [1952](https://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/40000288037). In that same year it was also known as [大統領年頭一般教書](https://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/40002147985). I can't find any other sources for 一般議会教書 so that might have been a one time translation choice. However, I'm unable to search newspapers/journals around the 1940s, which likely would have had a concrete formalized translation.

Comment: It makes sense that it would be called 一般議会教書 because it's presented to a joint session, or to the 議会 generally. But, I wonder why the 議会 part got dropped? 一般教書 just seems too broad without it.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it's probably just because it would be too long for a newspaper headline...